# Capturar / Interceptar Hook no Windows com [DELPHI]

Tags: delphi, windows

Antes de tudo eu sei como funciona os Ganchos no Windows, porem na pratica sou meio leigo, gostaria de saber se tem como Capturar / Interceptar Ganchos no Windows entre aplicações. E se alguém tiver algum tipo de material para estudo e treino agradeço.

Comment: O que é "Gancho no Windows"? Pesquisei no google e não me trás nenhuma resposta de entendimento.

Comment: Windows Hook Delphi https://goo.gl/YdU7iD

Comment: Eu não entendi, Aplicação A manda `WM_CLOSE` para Aplicação B, você quer saber se uma Aplicação C pode identificar essa comunicação?

Comment: Isso Júnior mais não só o WM_CLOSE igual você sito mais entre outros Ganchos(Hook) que aplicações estão a usar. Gostaria de uma material amplo para estudo tanto de cada gancho possível de fazer quanto como interceptar entre aplicações.